# How binary tree satisfies the red-black tree properties using C algorithm?

Tags: c, algorithm

I am a beginner and new here. I am trying to implement Red-Black Tree Porperties using the C program. I am trying to implement an input format that corresponds to postorder traversal.  An “R” corresponds to a red tree node, a “B” to a black tree node, and a “.” to the sentinel.  If a tree includes n data nodes, then the sentinel will be processed n + 1 times.

The input formate:  ..B..BB..B..B..R..RBRBB (including periods).

I am trying the following algorithm

```
// Implementing Red-Black Tree in C

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

enum nodeColor {
  RED,
  BLACK
};

struct rbNode {
  int data, color;
  struct rbNode *link[2];
};

struct rbNode *root = NULL;

// Create a red-black tree
struct rbNode *createNode(int data) {
  struct rbNode *newnode;
  newnode = (struct rbNode *)malloc(sizeof(struct rbNode));
  newnode->data = data;
  newnode->color = RED;
  newnode->link[0] = newnode->link[1] = NULL;
  return newnode;
}

// Insert an node
void insertion(int data) {
  struct rbNode *stack[98], *ptr, *newnode, *xPtr, *yPtr;
  int dir[98], ht = 0, index;
  ptr = root;
  if (!root) {
    root = createNode(data);
    return;
  }

  stack[ht] = root;
  dir[ht++] = 0;
  while (ptr != NULL) {
    if (ptr->data == data) {
      printf("Duplicates Not Allowed!!\n");
      return;
    }
    index = (data - ptr->data) > 0 ? 1 : 0;
    stack[ht] = ptr;
    ptr = ptr->link[index];
    dir[ht++] = index;
  }
  stack[ht - 1]->link[index] = newnode = createNode(data);
  while ((ht >= 3) && (stack[ht - 1]->color == RED)) {
    if (dir[ht - 2] == 0) {
      yPtr = stack[ht - 2]->link[1];
      if (yPtr != NULL && yPtr->color == RED) {
        stack[ht - 2]->color = RED;
        stack[ht - 1]->color = yPtr->color = BLACK;
        ht = ht - 2;
      } else {
        if (dir[ht - 1] == 0) {
          yPtr = stack[ht - 1];
        } else {
          xPtr = stack[ht - 1];
          yPtr = xPtr->link[1];
          xPtr->link[1] = yPtr->link[0];
          yPtr->link[0] = xPtr;
          stack[ht - 2]->link[0] = yPtr;
        }
        xPtr = stack[ht - 2];
        xPtr->color = RED;
        yPtr->color = BLACK;
        xPtr->link[0] = yPtr->link[1];
        yPtr->link[1] = xPtr;
        if (xPtr == root) {
          root = yPtr;
        } else {
          stack[ht - 3]->link[dir[ht - 3]] = yPtr;
        }
        break;
      }
    } else {
      yPtr = stack[ht - 2]->link[0];
      if ((yPtr != NULL) && (yPtr->color == RED)) {
        stack[ht - 2]->color = RED;
        stack[ht - 1]->color = yPtr->color = BLACK;
        ht = ht - 2;
      } else {
        if (dir[ht - 1] == 1) {
          yPtr = stack[ht - 1];
        } else {
          xPtr = stack[ht - 1];
          yPtr = xPtr->link[0];
          xPtr->link[0] = yPtr->link[1];
          yPtr->link[1] = xPtr;
          stack[ht - 2]->link[1] = yPtr;
        }
        xPtr = stack[ht - 2];
        yPtr->color = BLACK;
        xPtr->color = RED;
        xPtr->link[1] = yPtr->link[0];
        yPtr->link[0] = xPtr;
        if (xPtr == root) {
          root = yPtr;
        } else {
          stack[ht - 3]->link[dir[ht - 3]] = yPtr;
        }
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  root->color = BLACK;
}

// Delete a node
void deletion(int data) {
  struct rbNode *stack[98], *ptr, *xPtr, *yPtr;
  struct rbNode *pPtr, *qPtr, *rPtr;
  int dir[98], ht = 0, diff, i;
  enum nodeColor color;

  if (!root) {
    printf("Tree not available\n");
    return;
  }

  ptr = root;
  while (ptr != NULL) {
    if ((data - ptr->data) == 0)
      break;
    diff = (data - ptr->data) > 0 ? 1 : 0;
    stack[ht] = ptr;
    dir[ht++] = diff;
    ptr = ptr->link[diff];
  }

  if (ptr->link[1] == NULL) {
    if ((ptr == root) && (ptr->link[0] == NULL)) {
      free(ptr);
      root = NULL;
    } else if (ptr == root) {
      root = ptr->link[0];
      free(ptr);
    } else {
      stack[ht - 1]->link[dir[ht - 1]] = ptr->link[0];
    }
  } else {
    xPtr = ptr->link[1];
    if (xPtr->link[0] == NULL) {
      xPtr->link[0] = ptr->link[0];
      color = xPtr->color;
      xPtr->color = ptr->color;
      ptr->color = color;

      if (ptr == root) {
        root = xPtr;
      } else {
        stack[ht - 1]->link[dir[ht - 1]] = xPtr;
      }

      dir[ht] = 1;
      stack[ht++] = xPtr;
    } else {
      i = ht++;
      while (1) {
        dir[ht] = 0;
        stack[ht++] = xPtr;
        yPtr = xPtr->link[0];
        if (!yPtr->link[0])
          break;
        xPtr = yPtr;
      }

      dir[i] = 1;
      stack[i] = yPtr;
      if (i > 0)
        stack[i - 1]->link[dir[i - 1]] = yPtr;

      yPtr->link[0] = ptr->link[0];

      xPtr->link[0] = yPtr->link[1];
      yPtr->link[1] = ptr->link[1];

      if (ptr == root) {
        root = yPtr;
      }

      color = yPtr->color;
      yPtr->color = ptr->color;
      ptr->color = color;
    }
  }

  if (ht < 1)
    return;

  if (ptr->color == BLACK) {
    while (1) {
      pPtr = stack[ht - 1]->link[dir[ht - 1]];
      if (pPtr && pPtr->color == RED) {
        pPtr->color = BLACK;
        break;
      }

      if (ht < 2)
        break;

      if (dir[ht - 2] == 0) {
        rPtr = stack[ht - 1]->link[1];

        if (!rPtr)
          break;

        if (rPtr->color == RED) {
          stack[ht - 1]->color = RED;
          rPtr->color = BLACK;
          stack[ht - 1]->link[1] = rPtr->link[0];
          rPtr->link[0] = stack[ht - 1];

          if (stack[ht - 1] == root) {
            root = rPtr;
          } else {
            stack[ht - 2]->link[dir[ht - 2]] = rPtr;
          }
          dir[ht] = 0;
          stack[ht] = stack[ht - 1];
          stack[ht - 1] = rPtr;
          ht++;

          rPtr = stack[ht - 1]->link[1];
        }

        if ((!rPtr->link[0] || rPtr->link[0]->color == BLACK) &&
          (!rPtr->link[1] || rPtr->link[1]->color == BLACK)) {
          rPtr->color = RED;
        } else {
          if (!rPtr->link[1] || rPtr->link[1]->color == BLACK) {
            qPtr = rPtr->link[0];
            rPtr->color = RED;
            qPtr->color = BLACK;
            rPtr->link[0] = qPtr->link[1];
            qPtr->link[1] = rPtr;
            rPtr = stack[ht - 1]->link[1] = qPtr;
          }
          rPtr->color = stack[ht - 1]->color;
          stack[ht - 1]->color = BLACK;
          rPtr->link[1]->color = BLACK;
          stack[ht - 1]->link[1] = rPtr->link[0];
          rPtr->link[0] = stack[ht - 1];
          if (stack[ht - 1] == root) {
            root = rPtr;
          } else {
            stack[ht - 2]->link[dir[ht - 2]] = rPtr;
          }
          break;
        }
      } else {
        rPtr = stack[ht - 1]->link[0];
        if (!rPtr)
          break;

        if (rPtr->color == RED) {
          stack[ht - 1]->color = RED;
          rPtr->color = BLACK;
          stack[ht - 1]->link[0] = rPtr->link[1];
          rPtr->link[1] = stack[ht - 1];

          if (stack[ht - 1] == root) {
            root = rPtr;
          } else {
            stack[ht - 2]->link[dir[ht - 2]] = rPtr;
          }
          dir[ht] = 1;
          stack[ht] = stack[ht - 1];
          stack[ht - 1] = rPtr;
          ht++;

          rPtr = stack[ht - 1]->link[0];
        }
        if ((!rPtr->link[0] || rPtr->link[0]->color == BLACK) &&
          (!rPtr->link[1] || rPtr->link[1]->color == BLACK)) {
          rPtr->color = RED;
        } else {
          if (!rPtr->link[0] || rPtr->link[0]->color == BLACK) {
            qPtr = rPtr->link[1];
            rPtr->color = RED;
            qPtr->color = BLACK;
            rPtr->link[1] = qPtr->link[0];
            qPtr->link[0] = rPtr;
            rPtr = stack[ht - 1]->link[0] = qPtr;
          }
          rPtr->color = stack[ht - 1]->color;
          stack[ht - 1]->color = BLACK;
          rPtr->link[0]->color = BLACK;
          stack[ht - 1]->link[0] = rPtr->link[1];
          rPtr->link[1] = stack[ht - 1];
          if (stack[ht - 1] == root) {
            root = rPtr;
          } else {
            stack[ht - 2]->link[dir[ht - 2]] = rPtr;
          }
          break;
        }
      }
      ht--;
    }
  }
}

// Print the inorder traversal of the tree
void inorderTraversal(struct rbNode *node) {
  if (node) {
    inorderTraversal(node->link[0]);
    printf("%d  ", node->data);
    inorderTraversal(node->link[1]);
  }
  return;
}

// Driver code
int main() {
  int ch, data;
  while (1) {
    printf("1. Insertion\t2. Deletion\n");
    printf("3. Traverse\t4. Exit");
    printf("\nEnter your choice:");
    scanf("%d", &ch);
    switch (ch) {
      case 1:
        printf("Enter the element to insert:");
        scanf("%d", &data);
        insertion(data);
        break;
      case 2:
        printf("Enter the element to delete:");
        scanf("%d", &data);
        deletion(data);
        break;
      case 3:
        inorderTraversal(root);
        printf("\n");
        break;
      case 4:
        exit(0);
      default:
        printf("Not available\n");
        break;
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

can anyone please check the entire code and make a correction to where I am doing wrong.
The following test cases should be used for input data:

```
..B..BR..R..RBB
..B..BB..B..B..R..RBRBB
..B..BB..B..B..B..BRRBB
..B..BR..R..RBB..B..R..B..BRBBB
..R..RB..R..RBR..R..RB..R..RBRB
..R.B...RBR...RBB
..B..BR
..R.B
..B.R
```

and the output should look like this.

```
..B..BR..R..RBB
..B..BR..R..RBB
Input is a legal RB tree

..B..BB..B..B..R..RBRBB
..B..BB..B..B..R..RBRBB
Input is a legal RB tree

..B..BB..B..B..B..BRRBB
..B..BB..B..B..B..BRRBB
                    ^ Consecutive red node error

..B..BR..R..RBB..B..R..B..BRBBB
..B..BR..R..RBB..B..R..B..BRBBB
                            ^ Black height error

..R..RB..R..RBR..R..RB..R..RBRB
..R..RB..R..RBR..R..RB..R..RBRB
Input is a legal RB tree

..R.B...RBR...RBB
..R.B...RBR...RBB
Input is a legal RB tree

..B..BR
..B..BR
Input is a legal RB tree

..R.B
..R.B
Input is a legal RB tree

..B.R
..B.R
    ^ Black height error

..R.B..R.B
..R.B..R.B
          ^ Input string does not represent a tree

..#..$B
..#..$B
  ^ Bad character
```

Is it possible to implement this algorithm without using pointers and no recursion. Please guide me thanks.

Comment: You will have better luck at [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @smac89, should I need to post it at codereview.stackexchange.com or here is fine.

Comment: Your program's input and output seems to be completely different to the specified input and output format.

Comment: Yea you should post it there, and put a link here that points to the codereview one

Comment: @Ges Matteke - I can't depict a legal RB tree from the postorder traversal _..B..BB..B..B..R..RBRBB_; can you?